# groupby transform valueerror length of passed values

Tags: python, pandas

Hello can you help me understand what is the issue here and how to solve it?

```
dft = pd.DataFrame({'B': [0, 1, 2, 5, 4, 7, 2, 2, 2, 5, 6, 7]})
dft['user'] = ['a','b','c','b','a','c','a','b','b','c','a', 'c']

dft.groupby('user')['B'].transform(lambda row: row.ewm(span=2)).mean()
```

gives `ValueError: Length of passed values is 1, index implies 4.`

Comment: What is it that you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to calculate the expodential moving average per user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ewm` on the groupby directly, [support has been added for a while now](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16037):

```
dft = pd.DataFrame({'B': [0, 1, 2, 5, 4, 7, 2, 2, 2, 5, 6, 7]})
dft['user'] = ['a','b','c','b','a','c','a','b','b','c','a', 'c']

dft.groupby('user')['B'].ewm(span=2).mean()
```

output:

```
user    
a     0     0.000000
      4     3.000000
      6     2.307692
      10    4.800000
b     1     1.000000
      3     4.000000
      7     2.615385
      8     2.200000
c     2     2.000000
      5     5.750000
      9     5.230769
      11    6.425000
Name: B, dtype: float64
```

Comment: hi, do you know why the code I posted raises that error and what does it mean? I created this sample dataset because I'm following a tutorial and I wanted to understand how that bit works as there is some more working based on that. However, on my df it works fine but with the dummy df I get that error

Comment: You would need `apply` for it to work and the `mean` to be inside the `apply` call. Something like: `dft.groupby('user')['B'].apply(lambda row: row.ewm(span=2).mean())`, except here the output is sorted per group

Comment: Hey thanks for your time but I'm not looking for alternative solutions. I want to understand why that code bit doesn't work on this example when it works on the df I'm working on and what this error means

Comment: As I wrote in my comment, you need the `mean` **INSIDE** the function call, you're currently putting it outside

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that invocation of `mean()` should be a part of your lambda function.

So maybe your code should be:

```
dft.groupby('user')['B'].transform(lambda row: row.ewm(span=2).mean())
```

For your sample data I got:

```
0     0.000000
1     1.000000
2     2.000000
3     4.000000
4     3.000000
5     5.750000
6     2.307692
7     2.615385
8     2.200000
9     5.230769
10    4.800000
11    6.425000
Name: B, dtype: float64
```

Another hint is that *transform* invokes the passed function to each
**column**, not row.
So argument named *row* is in this case misleading.

Comment: I already pointed to that [commenting to my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71139246/groupby-transform-valueerror-length-of-passed-values/71139374?noredirect=1#comment125753018_71139374) ;)